# How to spot employee clocked in at two different locations

Tags: python, datetime, jupyter-notebook

In the employee time data shown below, reese is clocked in at both store1 and store2 with overlapping times on the same day. I'm trying to create a program that can capture this information.

I'm just not extraordinarily familiar with date and time python tools to use, since it's so encompassing. I've used datetime as well as pandas datetime/range tools but I'm having a hard time understanding how I might do this.

```
store   name    day  date       clockin       clockout
store1  reese   Mon  8/8/2022   8:55:32 AM    11:12:35 AM
store1  john    Mon  8/8/2022   8:55:27 AM    11:59:34 AM
store2  reese   Mon  8/8/2022   9:00:00 AM    12:00:00 PM
store2  bill    Mon  8/8/2022   12:36:35 PM   5:02:31 PM
```

I've looked at DateTimeRange [DateTimeRange](https://pypi.org/project/DateTimeRange/#:%7E:text=DateTimeRange%20is%20a%20Python%20library,time%20range%2C%20and%20so%20forth.) and I'm thinking that might be a tool I could use to accomplish this, but curious if there's any other input that might point me in the right direction.

Comment: FWIW, if you were doing this at scale in a real-world environment, a database query would make a lot more sense -- it's easier to get an efficient implementation with a join if one is indexing on the timestamps (specifically with an algorithm that allows not just exact lookups as Python dicts implement but efficient range lookups as well). There are some pretty simple algorithms that come to mind in Python, but "simple" doesn't necessarily mean "efficient".

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and I agree completely. Unfortunately, database access is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The following code computes a list containing a `(employee name, overlap start, overlap duration in hours)` tuple for each detected overlap. It works as follows: For each unique pair of observations `A` and `B` for a given employee, consider there to be no overlap if either `B` starts after `A` ends or `A` starts after `B` ends, and an overlap otherwise.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

# reconstruct data
data = """store name day date clockin clockout
store1  reese  Mon  8/8/2022  8:55:32 AM  11:12:35 AM
store1  john  Mon  8/8/2022  8:55:27 AM  11:59:34 AM
store2  reese  Mon  8/8/2022  9:00:00 AM  12:00:00 PM
store2  bill  Mon  8/8/2022  12:36:35 PM  5:02:31 PM"""
rows = data.split('\n')
cols = rows[0].split()
rows = [r.split('  ') for r in rows[1:]]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
for c in ['clockin', 'clockout']:
    df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df.date + ' ' + df[c])

# detect overlaps
conflicts = []
for employee in set(df.name):
    df_employee = df[df.name == employee]
    for (i, j) in combinations(df_employee.index, 2):
        slot_i = df_employee.loc[i, :]
        slot_j = df_employee.loc[j, :]
        if not ((slot_i.clockin > slot_j.clockout) or (slot_j.clockin > slot_i.clockout)):
            start = max(slot_i.clockin, slot_j.clockin)
            end = min(slot_i.clockout, slot_j.clockout)
            duration = abs((end - start) / pd.Timedelta('1 hour'))
            conflicts.append((employee, start, duration))
print(conflicts)
```

prints

```
[('reese', Timestamp('2022-08-08 09:00:00'), 2.209722222222222)]
```

Remark: This approach assumes `clockout > clockin` for all observations, as well as no overlaps of shifts for a given store and employee, which I believe should be guaranteed.